# Having absolute path in Manifest.mf Class-Path

Tags: java, classpath, manifest

I'm trying to use an absolute path in the `Class-Path` portion of a MANIFEST.MF file, but it doesn't seem to work.

The reason I'm using an absolute path is that the library in question is a proprietary library that I'm not at liberty to redistribute. It is installed on corporate machines on a constant path (/opt/...), so it makes sense for me to use this absolute path.

My manifest file is as follows:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Built-By: Me
Class-Path: /opt/path/to/library.jar
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.3.9
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_102
Main-Class: com.me.Main
```

The program runs fine (so the main class etc. is set correctly), but as soon as I try to load a class from `library.jar` I get a `NoClassDefFoundError`.

I have tried adding the following code the beginning of my main method:

```
ClassLoader cl = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();

URL[] urls = ((URLClassLoader)cl).getURLs();

for(URL url: urls){
    System.out.println(url.getFile());
}
```

but it only prints out the name of my jar file.

Apparently, running with "java -jar" also ignores the `$CLASSPATH` system variable, so even that does not seem to be an option.

Is there a solution besides copying (or sym-linking) the library to the location of my own jar?

Comment: Could you launch from a script with `java -cp ... com.supersecret.Main`?

Comment: I guess I could, although that would be slightly inconvenient. Still better than copying the offending jar, though.

Comment: See marked duplicate. The alternative is of course a symlink, no need to copy.